# How to add spaces before delimiter for each column using spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I need to add spaces based on conditions before delimiter for each column when writing from db to csv file using spring batch.

For example, i required spacing in csv file

```
Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4
AI22;FIENC234DK;EDEJJEDK;JEND4
OR2 ;JFJRN3D   ;DEDERF3E;FEF
EK3R;DJE3DJJEJE;JDJENEJ ;3NEN3
```

I have shown block of code run currently

```
  @Bean
ItemReader<CdVehicle> databaseToCsvItemReader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<CdVehicle> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql(QUERY_FIND_FRIENDS);
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CdVehicle.class));

    return databaseReader;
}
@Bean
ItemWriter<CdVehicle> databaseToCsvItemWriter() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<CdVehicle> csvFileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    String exportFileHeader = "CV20VEHID;CV20RFDPR;CV20USAGE;CV20CRVEH;CV20PERID;CV20SITE;CV27PROJ;CV27TYCAI;CV27PHASE;CV27MILLE;CV27CRV;O;CV20DTECL;CV20TEINT;CV20PRINCIPALE;CV20SECONDAIRE;CV20CRBIS;CV36TYPRX";
    StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);
    csvFileWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);
    String userhome = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String exportFilePath = userhome + "/tmp/cdv.txt";
    csvFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath));

    LineAggregator<CdVehicle> lineAggregator = newPersonLineAggregator();
    csvFileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);

    return csvFileWriter;
}

@Bean
public Step databaseToCsvStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("databaseToCsvStep")
            .<CdVehicle, CdVehicle>chunk(100)
            .reader(databaseToCsvItemReader())
            .writer(databaseToCsvItemWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
Job databaseToCsvJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("databaseToCsvJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(databaseToCsvStep())
            .end()
            .build();
}

private LineAggregator<CdVehicle> newPersonLineAggregator() {
    DelimitedLineAggregator<CdVehicle> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setDelimiter(";");
    FieldExtractor<CdVehicle> fieldExtractor = newPersonFieldExtractor();
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
    return lineAggregator;
}

private FieldExtractor<CdVehicle> newPersonFieldExtractor() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<CdVehicle> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    extractor.setNames(new String[] {"CV20VEHID","CV20RFDPR","CV20USAGE","CV20CRVEH","CV20DTAPP","CV20PERID","CV20SITE","CV27PROJ","CV27TYCAI","CV27PHASE","CV27MILLE","CV27CRV","CV27TYMOT","O","CV20DTECL","CV20TEINT","CV20PRINCIPALE", "CV20SECONDAIRE","CV20CRBIS","CV36TYPRX"});
    return extractor;
}
```

After running spring batch job i am getting the result for example as

```
    Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4
    AI22;FIENC234DK;EDEJJEDK;JEND4
    OR2;JFJRN3D;DEDERF3E;FEF
    EK3R;DJE3DJJEJE;JDJENEJ;3NEN3
```

in order to achieve spacing how to check column by column with conditions. Is some one have any idea how to check by column header name condition and give space before delimiter during iteration.

Comment: You should perhaps ask why you need some kind of fixed width in a CSV-like file, which is uncommon as there is the separator `;` anyway...

Comment: Have you considered using a `FormatterLineAggregator` instead of `DelimitedLineAggregator`? This would be more appropriate for your use case IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `String` [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) syntax by using the Spring Batch [`FormatterLineAggregator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/FormatterLineAggregator.html).  Just replace your existing `LineAggregator` implementation with the following:

```java
private LineAggregator<CdVehicle> newPersonLineAggregator() {
    FormatterLineAggregator<CdVehicle> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(newPersonFieldExtractor());
    lineAggregator.setFormat("%-4s;%-10s;%-8d;%-5s");
    return lineAggregator;
```